# When hyper-v starting ubuntu there's only mess screen

Tags: hyper-v

Ubuntu version: `ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64`

Trouble Screen:
[image: xxx]

Memory:
[image: xxx]

Processor:
[image: xxx]

Hard Drive:
[image: xxx]

Add Hardware:
[image: xxx]

What I've tried

I can use `ctrl + alt + F2` switch to command mode
Then again `ctrl + alt + F1` switch to the desktop to solve this problem.
But It looks like not the key point.

Comment: Have you enabled Enhanced Session mode?

Comment: @Ramhound HI, no , I don't .

Comment: Are you using the quick create method, or did you install manually? I have no problems with my quick-created Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @essjae  install manually